# VirtualMachine is not available from bridged interface outside the local network

Tags: networking, virtualization

I'm unable to connect to any service running in my VirtualMachine from Outside my local network.

My VM has the following configuration:

eth0 - Host Only Network
eth1 - Bridged Network (Therefore connected to my router, Valid IP Address and settings. e.g.: 192.168.178.20)

For testing purposes I install nginx or apache on my VM, after that I have a "test" WebSite waiting for me for testing purposes.

Now once I'm on the local network (Host e.g.: 192.168.178.21) I can reach the demo website using the IP Address of eth1. 
Everything works as expected and as it should be.

Though once I leave my local network or once I try to reach the server by my public IP address(e.g.:109.192.77.XX), I can't reach my server anymore. I also did setup a dyndns address pointing to my public IP address, though that doesn't work at all. I can't get a connection, a refused access or something. What I got before when testing to reach my network through curl -i was a 504 Gateway Timout Exception from WebProxy/1.0 Pre-Alpha though that didn't made sense to me.

I did open the right ports on my router and I can confirm that it's not my router or my ISP blocking what I'm trying here. To verify this I can simply open port 80 on my MacMini instead of my VM, which is running nginx and finally I can reach everything through my public IP address and through my dyndns (but this time on my MacMini, not the VM).

I really hope someone can help me as this is going to drive me crazy. I've been hanging on this for nearly 4 days now.

If you need further information, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe you have the rules in place properly for your MacMini's IP address and not your VM's IP address. Can you verify that your NAT settings are in place for your VM IP?

Is the WebProxy/1.0 Pre-Alpha something that is enabled on your router or is that a proxy on your VM itself? You might want to check the proxy configuration.

Comment: I can verify that my Port Opening rule points to the correct IP address of my VM, so that's not a problem.
The WebProxy must be something on the VM side as I can reach all other physical devices, though I test this with the simplest possible setup I still get this from time to time.

Comment: When you say from time to time, you mean it only happens intermittently when you are accessing externally?

What is the router OS and what is the VM OS? Did you find where the WebProxy configuration is?